# How to get AdMob information like impression number in an android app?

Tags: android, reporting, ads, admob

I need to track reporting from AdMob inside an android app. I would need information like number of impressions, clicks, ctr, ecpm and estimated revenue. Is there some kind of api which supports this?

Answer (score 1):

An AdMob API: https://developers.google.com/admob/api

## Request

```
curl -X POST https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/<your_publisher_id>/networkReport:generate \
       -H "'Authorization: Bearer <oauth2_access_token>" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --data @- << EOF
{
  "report_spec": {
    "date_range": {
      "start_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 2},
      "end_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 2}
    },
    "dimensions": ["APP", "AD_UNIT"],
    "metrics": ["AD_REQUESTS", "IMPRESSIONS", "ESTIMATED_EARNINGS"]
  }
}
EOF
```

## Get an Oauth2.0 access token

### With oauth2l

install: https://github.com/google/oauth2l

```
oauth2l header --json <path_to_secret_json> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report
```

*path_to_secret_json* - is one from the credentials page on the google cloud console.

### With curl

Replace the *oauth2_client_id* with the one you have in your “Cloud project credentials - OAuth 2.0 client IDs” page. (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=)

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadmob.report&response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob

- Open this link in incognito browser mode;
- Follow the instruction, and accept the consonant screen with AdMob publisher's account;
- Copy the code, it would be needed for the following request:

```
curl -L \
-d "client_id=<oauth2_client_id>" \
-d "client_secret=<oauth2_secret>" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
-d "code=<sign_in_code_from_the_previous_step>" \
-d "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

*oaut2_client_id* and *oauth2_secret* can be found on the OAuth 2.0 client Id page.

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "<access_token>",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

More details on the developers documentation: https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no api available for getting AdMob Data.

You can use this in [Mobile WebView](http://apps.admob.com/).

Thanks

Comment: I would need to do some calculations with the data first and then display the data, so WebView is not a good option, since I can't get the numbers. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Adv Server update after 12 Hours & still no api is available.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand correctly what you mean under "track reporting inside app", but guess you can do it using AdSense API.

to put it simple, every  app is associated with a adunit ID, so if you want to check the stats of a definite app, check:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.3/reference/accounts/reports/generate

```
accountId = your Publisher ID (pub-XXXXXXX)
startDate and endDate = The interval of dates you want to check
dimension = AD_UNIT_ID
metric = EARNINGS
With this query you'll have the required info, separated by App.
```

Comment: Hi kawabungajohn,

I tested this approach out only from the app and with an API key. So the current problem is I am getting a 404 error for an ad unit which for sure exists on that account. I tried using the ad unit's name, id (I found the options from the dimension and metric page) and I am still getting the 404 error. Could this be because I am using an AdMob ad unit and not AdSense? Since I read somewhere that the AdSense management API can be used with AdMob too what do you think could be the problem?